# Is sparse BLAS not included in BLAS?

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, lapack, blas

I have a working LAPACK implementation and that, as far as I read, contains BLAS.

I want to use SPARSE BLAS and as far as I understand [this website](http://www.netlib.org/blas/blast-forum/), SPARSE BLAS is part of BLAS.

But when I tried to run the code below from the sparse blas manual using

> g++  -o sparse.x sparse_blas_example.c -L/usr/local/lib -lblas && ./sparse_ex.x

the compiler (or linker?) asked for blas_sparse.h. When I put that file in the working directory I got:

```
ludi@ludi-M17xR4:~/Desktop/tests$ g++  -o sparse.x sparse_blas_example.c -L/usr/local/lib -lblas && ./sparse_ex.x
In file included from sparse_blas_example.c:3:0:
blas_sparse.h:4:23: fatal error: blas_enum.h: No such file or directory
 #include "blas_enum.h"
```

**What must I do to use SPARSE BLAS with LAPACK?** I could start moving a lot of header files to the working directory, but I gathered I already have them with lapack!

```
/* C example: sparse matrix/vector multiplication */

#include "blas_sparse.h"
int main()
{
const int n = 4;
const int nz = 6;
double val[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 2.4, 3.3, 4.1, 4.4 };
int indx[] = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3};
int jndx[] = { 0, 1, 4, 2, 0, 3};
double x[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
double y[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
blas_sparse_matrix A;
double alpha = 1.0;
int i;

/*------------------------------------*/
/* Step 1: Create Sparse BLAS Handle */
/*------------------------------------*/

A = BLAS_duscr_begin( n, n );

/*------------------------------------*/
/* Step 2: insert entries one-by-one */
/*------------------------------------*/

for (i=0; i< nz; i++)
{
BLAS_duscr_insert_entry(A, val[i], indx[i], jndx[i]);
}

/*-------------------------------------------------*/
/* Step 3: Complete construction of sparse matrix */
/*-------------------------------------------------*/
BLAS_uscr_end(A);

/*------------------------------------------------*/
/* Step 4: Compute Matrix vector product y = A*x */
/*------------------------------------------------*/

BLAS_dusmv( blas_no_trans, alpha, A, x, 1, y, 1 );

/*---------------------------------*/
/* Step 5: Release Matrix Handle */
/*---------------------------------*/

BLAS_usds(A);

/*---------------------------*/
/* Step 6: Output Solution */
/*---------------------------*/

for (i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%12.4g ",y[i]);
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You quote the Blas Technical Standard, not the LAPACK reference. LAPACK does not contain routines for sparse matrices, other than handling [some banded matrices](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node121.html).  There are other implementations such as [spblas](http://math.nist.gov/spblas/) and [sparse](http://www.netlib.org/sparse/) which follow the techincal standard and implement sparse BLAS. Typically, sparse operations are not considered part of BLAS, but an extension.

I would recommend using a higher level library, such as [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) because it will save you a significant amount of development time, with usually small performance costs. There is also [ublas](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/) which is part of boost, so if you are using boost as part of your project, you could give it a try, though it's not really optimised for performance. You can find a comprehensive list [here](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/la-sw.html) (again, note that LAPACK is not listed as having support for sparse operations).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that g++ does not find the required header files. So you need to add

```
-I path_to_header_files/
```

to the command line arguments. I.e, the directory where you copied blas_sparse.h to your working directory.

Answer (score 2):

as mentioned by Paul there is no sparse solver included in the standard BLAS. However Netlib has different computational routines called sparseblas [here](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/etemplates/node381.html).

I would recommend two famous direct solver for sparse matrices, which are : SuperLU [here](https://portal.nersc.gov/project/sparse/superlu/) and MUMPS [here](http://mumps.enseeiht.fr/)

you can find a full comparison between both libraries performance in this paper "***Analysis and Comparison of Two General Sparse Solvers for Distributed Memory Computers***"

we did a small scale benchmark between our code(I mean normal c++ loops) and superLu and the results is shown at this figure.
[image]