# Compiling Fortran code using BLAS (LAPACK) modules

Tags: ubuntu, fortran, gfortran, lapack, blas

I've just started to use Fortran and have a problem with using BLAS modules from (?) LAPACK in my program.

I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04, I've already installed (?) LAPACK and BLAS packages by command `sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev`. I've also downloaded LAPACK from http://www.netlib.org/lapack/ website and install it according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5N1QYWxAAL4).

My program is supposed to use `blas_sparse` module, so I wrote something like that:

```
program example

use blas_sparse

implicit none

    ! some code ...

end program example
```

I'm trying to compile my code (`example.F90`) using `gfortran` with a following command:

```
gfortran example.F90 -llapack -lblas
```

like on [this example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TsX2cRsDdNI) (1:11). However it does not work, the compiler returns:

```
example.F90:3:8:

 use blas_sparse
    1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file ‘blas_sparse.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory
```

What's the problem in here? I see three potential reasons:

1. The code is wrong.
2. The command I'm using to compile is incorrect.
3. LAPACK and BLAS are not really installed.

ad. 1.
Maybe I should add some module named `blas_sparse` to my code? Moreover it just moves the problem to another place bacause I still need to import somehow procedures from BLAS. Unfortunately I don't really know how does `use` command work, so I don't know what should I try to change.

ad. 2.
Maybe my compiler just don't know where `-llapack` and `-lblas` libraries are. I was trying trying to write it explicitly using

```
gfortran example.F90 -llapack -lblas -L/usr/local/lib
```

comand, because when installing LAPACK and BLAS I've created symbolic links to `liblapack.a` and `liblapack.a` (see ad. 3.). I don't know what are exactly `-llapack` and `-lblas` flags and it makes me difficult to check if the compiler 'can see' them.

ad. 3.
What I did to install BLAS and LAPACK on my computer is:

- downloading LAPACK 3.8.0 from netlib.org/lapack website
- using following commands to extract the library and install the files on my computer

:

```
tar zxvf lapack-3.8.0.tar.gz
cd lapack-3.8.0/
cp make.inc.example make.inc
make blaslib
make lapacklib
sudo ln -s /home/Download/lapack-3.8.0/liblapack.a /usr/local/lib/liblapack.a
sudo ln -s /home/Download/lapack-3.8.0/librefblas.a /usr/local/lib/librefblas.a
```

And also installing it via `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev
```

I'll be very thankful for any help to solve this problem.

EDIT:

I've actually found out that I should create those `.mod` files using `blas_sparse.f90`, `blas_sparse_namedconstant.f90` and `blas_sparse_proto.h` files from [BLAST website](http://www.netlib.org/blas/blast-forum/). First two of them I've just added to my code as modules and the gfortan compiler creates proper (I hope) `.mod` files. However the third one is written in C language, so I can't just put it into my code.

So now the question is how to bound the `.h` file with my code. Do I need to create some `makefile` or compile `.h` file to create the `.mod` file?

EDIT2:

It looks that just I didn't install sparse BLAS from the [BLAST website](http://www.netlib.org/blas/blast-forum/). What I have should done was:

- downloading the library:

```
wget -P target/directory/ http://www.netlib.org/toms/818
```

- unpacking the file:

```
mv 818 818.gz
gunzip 818.gz
```

- removing first three lines and ading `.sh` extension:

```
tail -n +4 818 > 818.sh; rm 818
```

- installing the library:

```
bash 818.sh
# before doing the following step read the notes below
bash INSTALL # this file has been created by 818.sh
./TESTER/test_all # running test
```

What I also needed to do, in the last step, was to edit `SOFTWARE/Makefile` and `INSTALL` files and create `TESTER/Makefile.GNU` file to use `gfortran` as a compiler.

After all I copied `blas_sparse.mod` file to the directory where my program is:

```
cp SOFTWARE/blas_sparse.mod blas_sparse.mod
```

and now I can compile the program using `gfortran` compiler:

```
gfortran example.F90 -llapack -lblas
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not just using the simple usual BLAS that most tutorials, questions and answers speak about. You are actually using the modern Fortran interfaces using modules.

Most compilers use .mod files for module descriptions and you have to tell the compiler where it will find those files for your sparse BLAS. In gfortran you do that using `-Ipath` where `path` is the path to those .mod files. It is quite similar to the need of the header files in C++ in a related question [Is sparse BLAS not included in BLAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190068/is-sparse-blas-not-included-in-blas)

Comment: But on my computer there are no such files. Those are created when compiling my program. As I realized I should prepare those files from the modules and include files from [BLAST](http://www.netlib.org/blas/blast-forum/ "BLAS Technical Forum"). And my problem is now, that I don't know how to create a `.mod` file using this include file (`blas_sparse_proto.h`) written in C.

Comment: No, a Fortran compiler can't use a .h file containing C code. If your library supports both Fortran and C, it will have separate header or mod files.

Comment: @MaciejK The .mod files are created by the compiler when installing the library.